# Timeout obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: .net, iis, .net-4.0, windows-server-2012

Our production application is throwing this error:

```
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
```

We stopped the application pool and then we start it users can get in but within minutes the connections (looking from the database), exceed more than 100 with the same login (impersonating an account) and the application starts throwing the above error. This application has been working fine for last 5 years and today it's throwing this error. Any troubleshooting ideas like what we should be looking at?

The application is using Windows Authentication and the application pool is impersonating a windows account. Within the application itself, the connection string is using a SQL account to connect to the database.

Comment: Do you have long queries? Are you sure you always close your connections ?

Comment: It's the very first page of the application and it does not let anyone login. We have found out that the application is leaking connections and we are going to fix that bit and hopefully that'll fix the application. However how the same piece of code has been running for last 5 years is the perplexing.

Comment: Maybe you have more users nowadays?